# Making hole in 1/8" Lead sheet with minimal dust/debris

Tags: metalwork

I want to cut some 6" diameter holes in 1/8" thick lead sheet that is 12"x12" up to 12" x 24" but would like to minimize dust and debris.

I was thinking that the best approach to minimizing dust and debris would be to use aviation shears to cut out the hole. However, the shears would need a starter hole to be made and this is mainly the hole I am asking about. Power drilling seems to not be an option.

Is 1/8" lead sheet soft enough that I could use a 1/2" drill in a pin vise to manually work it through? That would create debris but at least it would not get kicked up.

Alternatively I could use a 1/2" or 1" diameter hole punch on a 5-ton arbor press. That would probably produce even less dust but, Again, I am not sure if that could make it through a 1/8" sheet. I've been able to punch 2" diameter holes in 1/4" thick teflon, but don't have a good reference between lead and teflon.

Comment: Would melting a hole with a blowtorch produce hazardous fumes? I don't think it was a problem with electronics soldering where the hazard seemed to be from the flux.

Comment: @Transistor Yes it would as the melting temperature of pure lead is higher than tin-lead electronics solder. So a fortunate quirk is that melting tin-lead solder never gets the temperature high enough where the lead itself starts to vapourize. In any case, I don't have the access to or skills with a blow torch.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot that the tin-lead blend melting point is lower than either on their own.

Comment: @Transistor It's magic.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the lead did affect me. Meanwhile I found the "Bad Dog Biter" for cutting sheet metal. It nibbles at it so I suspect it generates bits rather than dust. I can't see if it could cut 1/8" though. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYMubCetlqU. Cool or not? (It still leaves you with the starter hole problem!)

Comment: @Transistor I did not know powered nibblers exist. I might get that just for regular sheet metal since a mill doesn't work so well for thin sheet.

Comment: Oooh, oooh. Look at this! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjNYs8ELGdk

Comment: @Transistor That's enough internet for you today.

Comment: My feeling is a punch should work fine for like a 1/4" or 3/8" hole, maybe more too. Lead is quite soft, a 1/8" sheet probably might have trouble to hold up its own weight if you stood it upright

Comment: How many holes do you want to make, and how accurate do they have to be?

Comment: @Hobbes Just two. Within 1/16" diameter tolerance would be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a hole cutter like a shear against a surface and hit or press through.

Similar to those pastry cutters, lead cuts easy enough.

Make in the diameters required 6", 12" even 9" etc

Something like this but only shown one half on the side view - the other half will start high on the low side of the first:

[image]

Comment: Okay so it sounds like you're saying a punching a 1/2" or 1" pilot hole on the 5-ton arbor press will work? I would have to make 6" diameter punch and I have little (that is to say zero) experience making punches. I don't think I could put out enough force for a 6" punch though. My only other reference is 2" holes in 1/4" thick Teflon and I imagine a 6" hole in 1/8" thick lead would be considerably higher.

Comment: Well I would look at using an old saw blade with an edge ground on it fitted into a thick enough wood plate  which you would then press through, have cut lead sheet with a stanley knife before...

Comment: A saw blade? Like flex the saw blade into a circle on a wood plate? Or are you talking about grinding an actual hole saw into a punch?

Comment: You can bend a hacksaw blade or an old saw blade from something like a band saw...

Comment: You might want to design the blade so it cuts from two points gradually - that would reduce the shearing force :)

Comment: Well, making a slanted circular punch or otherwise oblique is definitely beyond my zero experience making punches.

Comment: Just meant taper the cutting edge so that it does not cut all at once - do it with a grinder - only needs 1/4" on each half if the blade is two bits.

Comment: Just use a wood chisel

Comment: @DDuck Oh. that's an idea. I could just arbor press  a wood chisel or metal chisel to cut out the opening rather than the entire hole in one go.

Comment: Could also just use the chisel as a chisel like you were woodworking. You might be surprised about how soft lead is and how easy it is to work.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what's behind the sheet, you could use a hole punch (or wad punch, they're distinct) to put the initial hole through. After that use a hand nibbler, which will cut out a ribbon rather than produce dust or relatively small swarf.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the difference between a hole punch and a wad punch is. They both seem like straight metal posts centered on a circular steel cutting ring.

Comment: The bevel on a hole punch is on the inside, but on a wad punch it's on the outside. However for softer materials (i.e. leather but not lead) hole punches are often sharpened on the outside to make it easier for the bits to push through.

Answer (score 1):

A drill won't kick up dust. It will produce cuttings, but not dust unless you're abusing it.

Drill at slow speed and a feed rate that ensures uniform chip thickness. It The chips will be easy to handle, and the temperatures will not lead to lead vapour.

Furthermore, lead is *soft*. Punching it with hole punches made for steel should present no problem - and if you rig in a press you will not need a pilot hole.

Comment: Maybe not fine dust, but still debris and sometimes small particles which also get thrown by the drill and the motor.

Comment: The motor? The chips is heavy, and if you drill at low speed they will be large and not fly far.

Answer (score 1):

Use a chisel and hammer. A narrow chisel will allow you to make a hole within the tolerance you need.